# Is there something like LINQ to XML in python for appengine?

Tags: python, xml

Is there something that I can use to query XML in python like I can do in LINQ2XML? And if it would run on appengine too.
Pseudocode:

```
 xml = fetch("http://foo/bar.xml") 
 for person : xml.elements("person"):
   print(person.attribute("name"))
   for number : person.elements("number")
     print(" %s %d",(number.attribute("type"),number.attribute("value"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Example XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<container>
  <person name="Jim">
    <number type="home" value="000-000-0000"/>
    <number type="work" value="111-111-1111"/>
  </person>
  <person name="Fred">
    <number type="home" value="222-222-2222"/>
    <number type="work" value="333-333-3333"/>
  </person>
</container>
```

Example script:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

f = open('/path/to/xml/file', 'r')

xml = ElementTree(file=f)
for person in xml.findall('person'):
    print(person.attrib['name'])
    for number in person.findall('number'):
        print('%s -> %s' % (number.attrib['type'], number.attrib['value']))
```

prints:

```
Jim
home -> 000-000-0000
work -> 111-111-1111
Fred
home -> 222-222-2222
work -> 333-333-3333
```

It's part of Python 2.5, so it should work in App Engine. You can adapt the script to get the XML from a URL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ElementTree XML API](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) for that. Example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = ET.parse("bar.xml")
for person in xml.findall("person"):
    print person.attrib["name"]
    for number in person.findall("number"):
        print " %s %d" % (number.attrib["type"], int(number.attrib["value"]))
```